# Is there a way I can install tomcat7 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, tomcat

I would like to install tomcat7 (NOT tomcat8) on ubuntu 18.04. I figured I could enable the universe repo by doing the following

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

however, when I try and do sudo apt-get install tomcat7 it says it's not found?

Comment: Universe is already enabled by default typically.  Tomcat 7 is not provided through the repositories, probably because Tomcat 7 is old and probably unmaintained.  (Tomcat 8 is recently EOL upstream as of June 30th, and Tomcat 9 is now the maintained release)

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/tomcat7 so it seems possible yes.

Comment: Alright, so it seems doable? How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 7):

Add the following lines to the bottom of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

Answer (score 0):

`tomcat7` is EOL and even though it's listed in [this link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/tomcat7), it doesn't include the `tomcat7` server - it only includes the packages:

- `libservlet3.0-java`
- `libservlet3.0-java-doc`

For comparison, check out the source for `tomcat9` - it includes the `tomcat9` package:  https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/java/tomcat9